# InDesign changing colors of vector after exporting to PDF?

Tags: adobe-indesign, color, vector

I'm designing a document in InDesign where there is a vector image. To make the background seem continuous, I pulled a rectangle (sent it the backmost) and copied the color of the vector using the eyedropper tool into the rectangle. In short, I wanted the background color of the vector to be continuous with the whole document.

It worked great even on InDesign preview, but after exporting to PDF, there's a change. Could anyone pls help as to why this is happening and how to prevent it happen. Because, it would look ugly to have a border show up, which I was trying to conceal.

In InDesign,

[image]

In PDF,

[image]

Theres a slight difference in color in the right half in the lower image, if you could appreciate. That is my concern

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When sampling linked vector images in InDesign with the eyedropper tool, what is sampled is the **RGB preview**. In fact, I believe InDesign throws up a warning stating this when you do it. So it's *best guess* and never guaranteed accurate.

If you want the same yellow.. get the CMYK numbers from the vector file.. then fill the InDesign element with the same CMYK *numbers* not a sample using the eyedropper.

Comment: If it is an AI file, the swatch will get imported with it if I recall correctly.

Comment: @Yorik If the Ai file has **spot color swatches** *those* swatches will get imported. I do not believe CMYK, RGB, gradient, or pattern AI swatches get imported.

Comment: It's an EPS file does it makes a difference?

Comment: @Polisetty I don't think it does. InDesign only sees spot color swatches from linked files. I'd honestly have to test EPS to be certain though. I haven't used EPS in years.